# After opening a jquery-mobile popup and scrolling, clicking anywhere jumps me to the top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-collapsible, jquery-mobile-popup

I've developed a popup Menu which contains a couple of collapsibles and hyperlinks using jQueryMobile.

The problem is, when the popup is clicked and the menu is displayed, after having scrolled down, clicking on the page will bring me to the top of the page, near to the Menu button.

Since the content of the menu can appear quite long (especially on a mobile device), the scroll is necessary for me. But it does seem to prevent a normal behaviour on the page, as hyperlinks can't be clicked anymore.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is a fiddle with a reduced code: https://jsfiddle.net/48bqcgby/1/

```
<a data-rel="popup" href="#NestedPopup">Menu</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="NestedPopup">
  <div data-role="collapsibleset">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
      <h3>1st level header</h3>      
      <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h1>2nd level header</h1>
        <ul>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
          <li>hyperlink</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p>
Fieri, inquam, Triari, nullo pacto potest, ut non dicas, quid non probes eius, a quo dissentias. quid enim me prohiberet Epicureum esse, si probarem, quae ille diceret? cum praesertim illa perdiscere ludus esset. Quam ob rem dissentientium inter se reprehensiones non sunt vituperandae, maledicta, contumeliae, tum iracundiae, contentiones concertationesque in disputando pertinaces indignae philosophia mihi videri solent.

Denique Antiochensis ordinis vertices sub uno elogio iussit occidi ideo efferatus, quod ei celebrari vilitatem intempestivam urgenti, cum inpenderet inopia, gravius rationabili responderunt; et perissent ad unum ni comes orientis tunc Honoratus fixa constantia restitisset.

Illud autem non dubitatur quod cum esset aliquando virtutum omnium domicilium Roma, ingenuos advenas plerique nobilium, ut Homerici bacarum suavitate Lotophagi, humanitatis multiformibus officiis retentabant.

Verum ad istam omnem orationem brevis est defensio. Nam quoad aetas M. Caeli dare potuit isti suspicioni locum, fuit primum ipsius pudore, deinde etiam patris diligentia disciplinaque munita. Qui ut huic virilem togam deditšnihil dicam hoc loco de me; tantum sit, quantum vos existimatis; hoc dicam, hunc a patre continuo ad me esse deductum; nemo hunc M. Caelium in illo aetatis flore vidit nisi aut cum patre aut mecum aut in M. Crassi castissima domo, cum artibus honestissimis erudiretur.

Denique Antiochensis ordinis vertices sub uno elogio iussit occidi ideo efferatus, quod ei celebrari vilitatem intempestivam urgenti, cum inpenderet inopia, gravius rationabili responderunt; et perissent ad unum ni comes orientis tunc Honoratus fixa constantia restitisset.

Eminuit autem inter humilia supergressa iam impotentia fines mediocrium delictorum nefanda Clematii cuiusdam Alexandrini nobilis mors repentina; cuius socrus cum misceri sibi generum, flagrans eius amore, non impetraret, ut ferebatur, per palatii pseudothyrum introducta, oblato pretioso reginae monili id adsecuta est, ut ad Honoratum tum comitem orientis formula missa letali omnino scelere nullo contactus idem Clematius nec hiscere nec loqui permissus occideretur.

Quis enim aut eum diligat quem metuat, aut eum a quo se metui putet? Coluntur tamen simulatione dumtaxat ad tempus. Quod si forte, ut fit plerumque, ceciderunt, tum intellegitur quam fuerint inopes amicorum. Quod Tarquinium dixisse ferunt, tum exsulantem se intellexisse quos fidos amicos habuisset, quos infidos, cum iam neutris gratiam referre posset.

Hac ex causa conlaticia stipe Valerius humatur ille Publicola et subsidiis amicorum mariti inops cum liberis uxor alitur Reguli et dotatur ex aerario filia Scipionis, cum nobilitas florem adultae virginis diuturnum absentia pauperis erubesceret patris.

Victus universis caro ferina est lactisque abundans copia qua sustentantur, et herbae multiplices et siquae alites capi per aucupium possint, et plerosque mos vidimus frumenti usum et vini penitus ignorantes.

His cognitis Gallus ut serpens adpetitus telo vel saxo iamque spes extremas opperiens et succurrens saluti suae quavis ratione colligi omnes iussit armatos et cum starent attoniti, districta dentium acie stridens adeste inquit viri fortes mihi periclitanti vobiscum.

Eo adducta re per Isauriam, rege Persarum bellis finitimis inligato repellenteque a conlimitiis suis ferocissimas gentes, quae mente quadam versabili hostiliter eum saepe incessunt et in nos arma moventem aliquotiens iuvant, Nohodares quidam nomine e numero optimatum, incursare Mesopotamiam quotiens copia dederit ordinatus, explorabat nostra sollicite, si repperisset usquam locum vi subita perrupturus.

Cum autem commodis intervallata temporibus convivia longa et noxia coeperint apparari vel distributio sollemnium sportularum, anxia deliberatione tractatur an exceptis his quibus vicissitudo debetur, peregrinum invitari conveniet, et si digesto plene consilio id placuerit fieri, is adhibetur qui pro domibus excubat aurigarum aut artem tesserariam profitetur aut secretiora quaedam se nosse confingit.

Isdem diebus Apollinaris Domitiani gener, paulo ante agens palatii Caesaris curam, ad Mesopotamiam missus a socero per militares numeros immodice scrutabatur, an quaedam altiora meditantis iam Galli secreta susceperint scripta, qui conpertis Antiochiae gestis per minorem Armeniam lapsus Constantinopolim petit exindeque per protectores retractus artissime tenebatur.

Hoc inmaturo interitu ipse quoque sui pertaesus excessit e vita aetatis nono anno atque vicensimo cum quadriennio imperasset. natus apud Tuscos in Massa Veternensi, patre Constantio Constantini fratre imperatoris, matreque Galla sorore Rufini et Cerealis, quos trabeae consulares nobilitarunt et praefecturae.

Intellectum est enim mihi quidem in multis, et maxime in me ipso, sed paulo ante in omnibus, cum M. Marcellum senatui reique publicae concessisti, commemoratis praesertim offensionibus, te auctoritatem huius ordinis dignitatemque rei publicae tuis vel doloribus vel suspicionibus anteferre. Ille quidem fructum omnis ante actae vitae hodierno die maximum cepit, cum summo consensu senatus, tum iudicio tuo gravissimo et maximo. Ex quo profecto intellegis quanta in dato beneficio sit laus, cum in accepto sit tanta gloria.

Ergo ego senator inimicus, si ita vultis, homini, amicus esse, sicut semper fui, rei publicae debeo. Quid? si ipsas inimicitias, depono rei publicae causa, quis me tandem iure reprehendet, praesertim cum ego omnium meorum consiliorum atque factorum exempla semper ex summorum hominum consiliis atque factis mihi censuerim petenda.

Alios autem dicere aiunt multo etiam inhumanius (quem locum breviter paulo ante perstri
nxi) praesidii adiumentique causa, non benevolentiae neque caritatis, amicitias esse expetendas; itaque, ut quisque minimum firmitatis haberet minimumque virium, ita amicitias appetere maxime; ex eo fieri ut mulierculae magis amicitiarum praesidia quaerant quam viri et inopes quam opulenti et calamitosi quam ii qui putentur beati.

Nec vox accusatoris ulla licet subditicii in his malorum quaerebatur acervis ut saltem specie tenus crimina praescriptis legum committerentur, quod aliquotiens fecere principes saevi: sed quicquid Caesaris implacabilitati sedisset, id velut fas iusque perpensum confestim urgebatur impleri.
</p>
```

Comment: Can you add your Jquery code?

Comment: The entire code is above. The library is jQuery 1.12.4, see the following link: [link](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js)

Answer (score 0):

You can add this JS code:

```
var scrollPosition = 0;
$(document).scroll(function() {
    scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
});
$(document).on("popupafterclose", "#NestedPopup", function()
{
    $(window).scrollTop(scrollPosition);
});
```

*(doesn't work on JSFiddle due to document-in-document scrolling)*

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I can't get it working in my case. I'll see whether I can make my own modal to get rid of the jQueryMobile popup

Answer (score 0):

You can add something like:

```
<button style="position:fixed; top:10px; width:1px; right:0px; opacity:0; z-index:0;"></button>
```

Right after your:`<div data-role="popup" id="NestedPopup">`

In theory what this does is to add an invisible element that scrolls with the document thus gives something else to the browser to give focus to instead of the popup header. Like a decoy. It's a hack but it works. Please check the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/frspro/48bqcgby/3/

Hope it helps.